# UWP Entity Framework Core SQLITE crashes in release mode

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core, .net-native

I have made an update to my universal app using entityframeworkcore.sqlite 2.0 pre - release.

Everything works fine in debug config but when I switch too release config in VS and build, it throws the error "Internal Compiler Error Object reference not set to an object".

I think its to do with this .net Native stuff but I cant get too the bottom of it. Any suggestions on how to further debug the error?

Also when I tried to submit the app to the store I received the following in the failed submission report:

> FAILED
>   Supported APIs
>   Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>   API __acrt_iob_func in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API __stdio_common_vfprintf in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _cexit in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _configure_narrow_argv in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _crt_at_quick_exit in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _crt_atexit in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _except1 in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _execute_onexit_table in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _initialize_narrow_environment in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _initialize_onexit_table in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _initterm in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _initterm_e in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _localtime64_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _register_onexit_function in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _seh_filter_dll in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _wassert in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API fflush in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API free in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API log in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API malloc in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API qsort in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API rand_s in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API strcmp in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API strlen in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API strncmp in ucrtbased.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API __std_type_info_destroy_list in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API _except_handler4_common in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API memcmp in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API memcpy in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API memmove in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.
>   API memset in vcruntime140d_app.dll is not supported for this application type. sqlite3.dll calls this API.

Followed by

Debug configuration test
FAILED
Debug configuration
Error Found: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:
The binary sqlite3.dll is built in debug mode.

Comment: This is a known issue with the .NET Native compiler. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8461. For now, I'd suggest using the latest **Stable** version (1.1.2) instead of the preview one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I downgraded to 1.1.2 and it compiled in release mode. Still failing the windows certification though.